# Use loopback token authentication for authentication of socket.io

Tags: strongloop, socket.io-1.0

I'm working with loopback 2.0 and socket.io 1.0.6.

I'd like to use loopback authentication method for authencation of socket.io.

I found the method to authenticate users in `loopback/lib/middleware/token.js`.
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/lib/middleware/token.js

Then I write like below.

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var ioapp = module.exports = socketio;

function socketio(server) {
  var io = require('socket.io')(server);

  // auth
  io.use(function(socket, next) {
    loopback.token()(socket.request, null, next);
  });

  // listeners
  ...

  return io;
};
```

But actually it won't work and causes error like this.

```
/Users/.../project_root/node_modules/loopback/lib/models/access-token.js:201
    id = req.param(params[i]);
             ^
TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'param'
    at tokenIdForRequest (/Users/ksuzuki/Projects/appsocially/repo/chat-center/node_modules/loopback/lib/models/access-token.js:201:14)
    at Function.AccessToken.findForRequest (/Users/ksuzuki/Projects/appsocially/repo/chat-center/node_modules/loopback/lib/models/access-token.js:123:12)
    at /Users/ksuzuki/Projects/appsocially/repo/chat-center/node_modules/loopback/lib/middleware/token.js:53:16
    at Array.0 (/Users/ksuzuki/Projects/appsocially/repo/chat-center/server/socket.js:15:28)
    at run (/Users/ksuzuki/Projects/appsocially/repo/chat-center/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:114:11)
    at Namespace.run (/Users/ksuzuki/Projects/appsocially/repo/chat-center/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:126:3)
    at Namespace.add (/Users/ksuzuki/Projects/appsocially/repo/chat-center/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:155:8)
    at Client.connect (/Users/ksuzuki/Projects/appsocially/repo/chat-center/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:67:20)
    at Server.onconnection (/Users/ksuzuki/Projects/appsocially/repo/chat-center/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:309:10)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

I guess this is because I pass the wrong object type to `loopback.token()` method. How should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loopback.token is an express middleware and it expects the first argument to be an express Request.